# How to insert multiple rows from a table to another table based on date condition (PHP-MySQL-Query)?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables as it is seen in the schematic picture. I want to copy data from three columns `URI`, `fields` and `details` in `table1` and insert them into `table2` if date in `table1` is greater than 12/11/2013. Something like below query:

`INSERT INTO table2 (all_links, fields_one, fields_two) 
FROM table1 (URI, fields, details) WHERE date>"12-11-2013 00-00-00";`

Could you please help to solve this problem?

[image: schematic picture]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select multiple columns from a table and insert data into another table in a different database in PHP-MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594005/select-multiple-columns-from-a-table-and-insert-data-into-another-table-in-a-dif)

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, we tend to recommend that questions are not duplicated here, as we feel they create duplicate work. There's a couple of your questions that appear to be like this. Since you're new, you need not worry about it, but if you can compress each problem into a single question, rather than asking another one to do the same thing, that does help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like

```
INSERT INTO table2 (all_links, fields_one, fields_two) 
select URI, fields, details FROM table1 
WHERE date > "12-11-2013 00-00-00";
```

In case tables are in different DB (assuming `dbo` is default owner)

```
INSERT INTO DB1.dbo.table2 (all_links, fields_one, fields_two) 
select URI, fields, details FROM DB2.dbo.table1 
WHERE date > "12-11-2013 00-00-00";
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your code and got this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in...`. Is there something missed in syntax?

Comment: Try now, with the edited query (using the entire datetime string)

Comment: could you please modify your code if tables are in different databases? thanks,

Comment: Just use `dbname.owner.tablename` instead of `tablename`. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
      SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
      FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

And check the documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (all_links, fields_one, fields_two) select URI, fields, details from table1 where date>"12-11-2013 00-00-00";
```