# Select multiple columns from a table and insert data into another table in a different database in PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have to select data from a table in a database and insert them into another table in a different database. The below code returns the `$select_query` OK, but the `$insert_query` is not OK. Could you please correct the code and let me know your response?

```
$host1 = "localhost";
$user1 = "jackpot";
$pass1 = "jackpot";
$db1 = "pinkapple";
$host2 = "localhost";
$user2 = "jackpot";
$pass2 = "jackpot";
$db2 = "blueberry";

$mysql_connection1 = mysql_connect($host1, $user1, $pass1);
mysql_select_db($db1, $mysql_connection1) or die(mysql_error());
$select_query = mysql_query("SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM tree WHERE date_entered > '2014-01-01 16:22:00'", $mysql_connection1);
$number = mysql_num_rows($select_query);

    if ($select_query) {
        echo "Select Query is OK <br>";
        echo $number ."<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Select Query is  not OK <br>";
    }

$mysql_connection2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $pass2, true);

mysql_select_db($db2, $mysql_connection2) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query)) {
    $field1 = $row['field1'];
    $field2 = $row['field2'];
    $field3 = $row['field3'];
    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', '$field3')", $mysql_connection2);
        if ($insert_query) {
            echo "Insert Query is OK <br>";
        } else {
            echo "Insert Query is not OK <br>";
        }
}
mysql_close($mysql_connection1);
mysql_close($mysql_connection2);
```

below you can see the schematic image of the tables.

[image]

Comment: You forgot the `VALUES` keyword on your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: empty insert statement??

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, I fixed the Values, still returning `Insert Query is not OK`

Comment: It was because you weren't grabbing the original query values, using the keyword values doesn't change anything if you don't establish values

Comment: what is your output on `mysqli_num_rows($select_query)` ?

Comment: @wishchaser, I got the warning `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, resource given in...`

Comment: @Apiah So you have problem with your SELECT query in the first place. Please check table name, column names and the WHERE clause condition. To be sure, store the query in a variable, say `$query` and echo it. Paste the echoed query in your mysql administration UI, such as a PHPMyAdmin and see what is the actual mistake you are doing.

Comment: @wishchaser, thank you for your time and help. I echoed the `$number = mysql_num_rows($select_query);
` and it returned `20`. would you also recommend something for insert query?

Comment: @Apiah Yes, the same thing as said in my previous comment. See if you have problems in your INSERT statements by echoing the query. Not `$select_query`. The original query `echo "INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', '$field3')";` as in Chitowns24's answer.

Comment: @wishchaser, thank you again for your comment. From `mysql_error($insert_query)`, I get this error message `Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in...`

Comment: @Apiah, I don't think it is a proper way to use `mysql_error()` function. In your case, it must be something like `if(!$insert_query) die(mysql_error());`

Comment: And Please `echo "INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', '$field3')";` and check for errors in the output echoed.

Comment: @Apiah Please update your question with the latest code you are using. It will help us see what you are doing.

Comment: @wishchaser, could you please check this query? `$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES ('hello world', 'hello world', 'hello world')", $mysql_connection2);
`, I can not even insert the above into the database. I checked the database connection and it was also ok.

Comment: @Apiah Yes it is correct if `$mysql_connection2 is valid`, `The connection has a database named blueberry`, `there is a table named jungle in the database blueberry` and `the table jungle contains the 3 columns desk1, chair1 and table1`

Comment: @wishchaser, I updated the code. Also, this runs fine `if ($mysql_connection2) {echo "connection is OK";}`

Comment: @Apiah, What about `if(mysql_select_db($db2, $mysql_connection2)){echo "Database Selected";} `

Comment: @wishchaser, yes it echoes `"Database Selected"`

Comment: @Apiah, `if(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jungle LIMIT 1",$mysql_connection2)){echo "Table exists";}`

Comment: @wishchaser, yes, echoes `"Table exists"`

Comment: @Apiah, `if(mysql_query("SELECT desk1, chair1, table1 FROM jungle LIMIT 1",$mysql_connection2)){echo "All columns exist";}`

Comment: @wishchaser, yes prints `"All columns exist"`

Comment: @Apiah, `if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO jungle SET desk1='success', chair1='success', table1='success'", $mysql_connection2)){echo "Values inserted successfully"}`

Comment: @wishchaser, sorry no luck to echo the sentence

Comment: @Apiah, Is there any column in the table jungle that cannot be empty? Maybe a unique or primary key. Set a value to that column in insert statement.

Comment: @wishchaser, yes I think so, please let me check my table structure, I think one of columns doesn't have the default value,

Comment: @wishchaser, thanks a lot, yes you are right, one of the columns doesn't have the default value and I set a value to the column; problem is solved. I appreciate all your time and help, cheers

Comment: @Apiah Glad you made it work finally. If you had executed `INSERT INTO jungle SET desk1='success', chair1='success', table1='success'` in your phpMyadmin or something similar, you would have found the issue long ago. Anyway Cheers:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to establish the values?

```
"INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)"
```

You should collect the data from the first select and then you can set the pertinent values in your insert statement

You can do that using the `mysql_fetch` statement

```
$mysql_connection2 = mysql_connect($host2, $user2, $pass2, true);
mysql_select_db($db2, $mysql_connection2) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query))
{
    $field1 = $row['field1'];
    $field2 = $row['field2'];
    $field3 = $row['field3'];
    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2', '$field3')",$mysql_connection2);

    if ($insert_query) {
      echo "Insert Query is OK <br>";
    } else {
      echo "Insert Query is not OK <br>";
    }

}
```

This statement loops through your select statement and inserts a row for every returned result using your `INSERT` statement

But really you should also look into `mysqli` because `mysql` is depreciated. This is however the basic logic behind what you are doing

Comment: thanks for your response. I changed it to "INSERT INTO jungle (desk1, chair1, table1) VALUES (field1, field2, field3)", but still no luck! Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Have you output what is returned from the `select_query`?

Comment: thanks again, your answer is fine, there was a problem in my table structure that one column did not have the default value, so I gave a value to the column in insert query.

Answer (score 1):

I get the post is old, but I had to do the same thing and used mysqli as is suggested.  Only thing I would caution is this example uses just a integer field and a short text field.  If you have additional fields you should use prepared statements, however as I know the data here is fixed and contains no special characters so this will be fine for my needs.

```
<?php
include "database1.php"; // Using database connection file here conn variable is $connj
include "database2.php"; // Using database connection file here conn variable is $conn


// select data and put values in array from first database
$selectsql = mysqli_query($connj,"SELECT id,name FROM table1 ORDER BY id ASC");
$result = mysqli_query($connj, $selectsql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectsql))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];

    //replace query into second table in second database    
    $replacesql = mysqli_query($conn, "REPLACE INTO table2 (name,id) VALUES ('$name','$id');");
    
    if($replacesql)
    {
        echo "Replace Successful<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "replace error<br>";
    }
}
?>
```